# gettting 404 method not found when using rest API to create enterprise search dataStore, is it broken?

Tags: vertex-ai-search

not sure where else to turn to here. Trying to use rest API to create a dataStore for a Vertex AI Search app(a.k.a Google Enterprise Search / Generative AI App Builder).

I have followed the documentation here https://cloud.google.com/generative-ai-app-builder/docs/create-data-store-es to try create a dataStore and ingest unstructured data from Cloud Storage.

The authentication is not an issue.

According to the docs here  https://cloud.google.com/generative-ai-app-builder/docs/reference/rest/v1alpha/projects.locations.collections.dataStores/create it is a valid method so i'm unsure why im getting a 404 method not found response. Ideally i would have used PHP library but its not supported at the moment so im forced to use REST.

Here is the code I am using if that helps:

```bash
$url = 'https://discoveryengine.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/xxxxxx/locations/global/collections/default_collection/dataStores?dataStoreId=xxxxxx';

$data = [
    'name' => 'xxxxxx',
    'displayName' => 'xxxxxx',
    'industryVertical' => 'GENERIC',
    'solutionTypes' => ['SOLUTION_TYPE_SEARCH'],
    'contentConfig' => 'CONTENT_REQUIRED',
    'searchTier' => 'ENTERPRISE',
    'searchAddOns' => ['LLM'],
    'companyInfo' => [
        'displayName' => 'xxxxxx'
    ]
];

$headers = [
    'Authorization: Bearer xxxxxx',
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'X-Goog-User-Project: xxxxxx'
];

// Initialize cURL session
$ch = curl_init();

// Set cURL options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Execute the cURL request
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Check for errors
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'cURL Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

// Close cURL session
curl_close($ch);
```

I was expecting this request to create a dataStore for a Vertex AI Search App

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you will need to create data stores/search engines through the Cloud Console instead of the REST API or Client Libraries. The documentation will been updated soon to specify this. This page shows how to create a data store using the Cloud Console and Import Data using the REST API or client libraries.

https://cloud.google.com/generative-ai-app-builder/docs/create-data-store-es

Comment: Is that still the case? 
on the Console we can't specify industryVertical and then we can't have an endpoint after that since it's not specified by default..

Comment: The REST API/client library method for creating data stores has been added https://cloud.google.com/generative-ai-app-builder/docs/reference/rest/v1alpha/projects.locations.collections.dataStores/create

And the documentation for REST and the Console has been updated.

Also, for industryVertical, this is determined based on if you create a generic search/recommendations engine or a media search/recommendations engine in the console. https://cloud.google.com/generative-ai-app-builder/docs/create-app-data-store-media-recommendations