# List data store under "search & conversation" with rest api

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to list all data store information in a project. I found the way to do this in [this](https://cloud.google.com/generative-ai-app-builder/docs/reference/rest/v1alpha/projects.locations.dataStores/list) documentation. However, for some reason, when I try the method, I always got 404 method not found error. Following is my command

```
curl -X GET \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token --impersonate-service-account=datastore-test@yingruiz-tatc.iam.gserviceaccount.com)" \
    "https://discoveryengine.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/yingruiz-tatc/locations/global/dataStores"
```

And this is the error message I got:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Method not found.",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
}
```

can someone please tell me where I did wrong?

Comment: Can you check if you have the permissions to list datastores by following this [link](https://cloud.google.com/generative-ai-app-builder/docs/access-control)?

Comment: thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I have checked the permission. I got 403 error before, but after adding the permission, I got 404

Comment: Normally the 404 code means that a server could not find a client-requested web page.Could you try again after replacing the project name with the project number in the url (eg:`https://discoveryengine.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/1234/`). Can you take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77156462/) also.
Since this is a public platform please remove your project name and service account name from this stack thread.